Сan't get the google avatar link
this is a link to my google avatar, which is saved on my server
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocKK6uA2DcFFe5MAOtMhGdir04H4FUM9q9ufZW7538UvQ63sIoM=s96-c.
I can't display the avatar on the front, please help.
store
async fetchUser(id) {
            try {
                const res = await $axios.get(`/api/user/${id}`, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('authToken')}`
                    }
                });
                this.id = res.data.id;
                this.name = res.data.name;
                this.email = res.data.email;
                this.image = res.data.image;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
            }
        },

script
<script setup>

import {storeToRefs} from "pinia";

const { $userStore } = useNuxtApp()

const route = useRoute();
const { name, image } = storeToRefs($userStore)
   
onMounted(async () => {
  const userId = route.params.id;
  if (userId) {
    await $userStore.fetchUser(userId);
  } else {
    console.error('Route param id is undefined');
  }
});

const user = computed(() => $userStore.user);

</script>

Template
  <img
          :src="user?.image || '/user-placeholder.png'"
          class="rounded-full !visible  hidden flex-grow basis-[100%] items-center lg:!flex lg:basis-auto"
          style="height: 50px; width: 50px; margin-left:20px; cursor: pointer"
          alt=""
          loading="lazy" />

Tell me what to do, the avatar just doesn't show up.

Try inspecting the page and check the value of image src.

Md. Zayed Hassan error Route param id is undefined But I still have no idea what to do next. I've checked everything. What do I do? Check the server request?

Image ID found: ACg8ocKK6uA2DcFFe5MAOtMhGdir04H4FUM9q9ufZW7538UvQ63sIoM

try using


this.image=res.data.picture



what error code did you get?

console.log('Image:', image.value);  Image:   empty

this.image=res.data.image also Image: empty + Route param id is undefined

store
   async fetchUser(userId) {
            try {
                const { data } = await useFetch(`/api/user/${userId}`);
                this.user = data.value;
                console.log(this.user)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Failed to fetch user:', error);
            }
        },

script
onMounted(async () => {
  if (userId.value) {

    await $userStore.fetchUser(userId.value);
  } else {
    console.error('Route param id is undefined');
  }
});

const user = computed(() => $userStore.user);

const computedAvatar = computed(() => {
  return user.value?.avatar || '/user-placeholder.png';
});

template
 <img
       style="cursor:pointer"
       class="rounded-full"
       width="65"
       :src="computedAvatar" alt=""
   >

